# Generic function returning ModelAndView or RedirectView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

It bothers me that `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView` do not have a common `supertype`.

I'd like to have a function that does something like:

```
if (userShouldBeRedirected) 
    return new RedirectView(path);

return new ModelAndView("file.html");
```

What I want to avoid:

- extend the two classes and implement a custom `interface`
- have the function return `Object`

Comment: Just return a `String` view name. For the `RedirectView`, prefix that path with `redirect:`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis forgot to mention that I'll have to build my `ModelAndView` with `addObject(attr,val);`

Comment: Then build just `ModelAndView` (empty for the redirect) with a view name of `redirect:yourPath`.